# Difference in HashMap Behaviour in Debug and Normal Release Mode

Tags: java, spring, collections, hashmap

I have a requirement to add key and values into hashmap dynamically from property files without restarting the server. So i have created a static hashmap in my object which loads data from file on server startup. So on subsequent addition of properties, I will update this hashmap. Here is my HashMap instantiation.

```
private static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

So now, when I add a property I initialize the map and now if I execute my main method, since it is a same classloader, I still see a new value in my map when I viewed in DEBUG mode.
Eg: If I am adding Europe=EU as new property, I see this value in Debug mode with other properties as [Europe=EU, India=IN] and if I run a line map.get("Europe") I get value as null.

I am not clear on this behavior. Is it something not commit to instance or am I doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```java
public class CountryMap {

    private static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    private static final CountryMap countrymap = new CountryMap();

    static {
        initmap();
    }

    private static void initmap() {
        IPropertyReader reader = (IPropertyReader) MyAppContext
                .getInstance().getBean("propreader"); //To read from location  files
        try {
            Properties props = reader.loadPropertyFile();
            Set<Entry<Object, Object>> propset = props.entrySet();
            for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : propset) {
                map.put((String) entry.getKey(),
                        entry.getValue().toString());
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

    public static CountryMap getInstance() {
        return countrymap;
    }

    public String getvalue(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public void addtomap(String key, String value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code, please. And tell more about your environment. If you possibly access this map from multiple threads at the same time you may want to use a concurrent version of a `Map`.

Comment: I imagine it's a problem with your code...

Comment: added code for more understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a hashmap? Maybe go with something already existing like commons configuration and their reloading strategy?
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_filebased.html

Comment: Basically, I am trying to update property file from one controller and want to use the same in other running process. So read and write are completely different threads all together. Let me know if apache-commons configuration helps here.

Comment: Well, if one thread will modify the file, the configuration object will be updated accordingly, so it's just a matter of accessing it from another thread. Should be ok. Give it a try, it's quite easy to set up.